# Change attribute from managed to unmanaged in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to know if there is any way to change the attribute state from managed to unmanaged in crm 2015

Answer (score 2):

There is no *supported* way of changing an attribute from managed to unmanaged.  However it certainly is possible and I have done quite a bit of this sort of work over the last half year.  This involves directly changing the ismanaged property of selected records in the attribute and related metadata tables.

The primary reason you would want to make a component managed is so that you can remove it.  So far I have been able to remove the following managed components by first setting underlying ismanaged values to false and then deleting normally through the CRM customizations page:

- Text fields
- Decimal fields
- Yes/No values and Option Sets
- 1:N and N:N Relationships

I have not worked out removing the following components

- Money Fields - conceptually no harder than option sets
- Entities - Much more complicated
- Entity Properties such as notes and activities - Very complicated

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  You'd have to uninstall the managed solution, create the attribute in the environment (which would be created as unmanaged), remove the attribute from your managed solution, then reimport your managed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the base column for money fields to IsManaged false